# Determine API work 2 way SSL and another one work one way SSL

Tags: wso2, api-manager

Suppose I have two API and the required is one should be work with two-way SSL and the second should be work with one-way SSL. could you please guide me if can be implemented

Answer (score 0):

You can write a handler for Mutual SSL and engage that with your APIs. [This blog post](http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/06/02/securing-apis-using-mutual-ssl-with-wso2-api-manager/) discusses it. From it you can get some idea on how to proceed.

Comment: I already read what You mentioned.when I enable Mutual SSL with WSO2 API Manager it's will be enabled for app API.

Comment: what do you mean by app API?

Comment: I need Add two New API first one one-way SSL seconds one work with two-way SSL

Comment: it's working when I enable SSLVerifyClient it's required for all API work with one-way SSL before must use two-way SSL